# read excelFile in java Apache Poi?

Tags: apache-poi, read-write, anylogic

I tried to read an excel file in Anylogic software(is based on Eclipse).

I use Poi to read the file but i get `java.io.FileNotFoundException` when I launch the program.

Can you help me plese?

This is the code:

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("C://Users/leonardo/Desktop/ListaAttesa.xlsx");
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
```

Comment: Does that file actually exist at that path?

Comment: Check if file actually exists at the path specified. Also note `HSSFWorkbook` class handles `xls` file format, not `xlsx` one. You should use `XSSFWorkbook` in order to work with `xlsx` files.

Answer (score 1):

You can verify that your file exists at that place via

```
if(!new File("C://Users/leonardo/Desktop/ListaAttesa.xlsx").exists()) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("File not found!");
}
```

And as pointed out in the comments, for a .xlsx file you should use XSSFWorkbook, not HSSFWorkbook.

Answer (score 1):

That error has nothing to do with the file itself or the way you are trying to read it. It just tells you that at the given path (**"C://Users/leonardo/Desktop/ListaAttesa.xlsx"** in your case) the file does not exist. I wonder why you have a double slash behind C: and guess that this is the error in this case.
BTW: You might be interested in the fact that there is an excel file block in the connectivity group that can be dragged into the workspace and then be used programmatically. But I dont know your use case so I cannot tell you if it is appropriate in your case.